# PDO Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active

Tags: php, orm, simpletest

I keep getting this issue with PDO, where this error crops up in my tests.

```
<?php

require_once('simpletest/unit_tester.php');
require_once('simpletest/reporter.php');
require_once('../model.php');

class TestOfCallMapper extends UnitTestCase {
 function testOfReturnsAll() {
 }

 function setUp() {
  R::setup("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=poo", root, '');
  $this->destroySchema();
  $this->createSchema();
 }

 function tearDown() {
  $this->destroySchema();
 }

 private function createSchema() {
  R::exec(file_get_contents('../database/create_schema.sql'));
 }

 private function destroySchema() {
  R::exec(file_get_contents('../database/destroy_schema.sql'));
 }

}

$test = new TestOfCallMapper('Test of CallMapper Methods');
$test->run(new HTMLReporter());
```

I'm pretty sure that what's happening is that the stuff in my create_schema file is continuing to execute and blocking other queries from running since it tells me the queries are unbuffered. I switched away from using PDO because this didn't make sense to me and started using a different ORM called Redbean. Unfortunately, I'm getting this irritating error again, and I can't seem to fix it, since apparently Redbean sits on top of PDO. When I used PDO, I tried setting the option to turn on buffered queries and it didn't work. Outside of my tests, the method seems to work fine, but I'm not really sure that's acceptable.

Comment: If you want us to help you, show us the PDO code, not some other class you wrote that calls code that uses PDO. Basically, if you run a query that returns results, you need to fetch those results before you run another query, or at least clear the buffer or close the connection.

Comment: I don't know where the PDO code itself is. It disappears somewhere in this 3rd party ORM. PHP helpfully does not tell me where.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought they were your own functions

Comment: It's `exec()` that's waiting for the console command to finish. Not PDO. Are you sure you set the switch on for running the command in background: `>/dev/null 2>&1 &`?

Comment: Thanks stillstanding. I haven't set that switch and honestly haven't heard of it. I'm running XAMPP. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Ok stillstanding, I did some research. The function in question is basically analogous to PDO::exec(). Are we talking about the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed itself when I switched to a new server. I never found the problem.